Nouveau error - trying to get external gpu to work with libreboot/gnuboot
I recently flashed my BIOS chip with either GNUboot and libreboot. But I have not been able to get my external graphics card to work.
The only error I could find regarding to nouveau is:
... vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
Does anyone know what could cause this error, or in what direction to look?
Everything worked before flashing. Now only able to get display with serial cable and on-board graphics.

oh, that's a pretty special setup. You'll probably have to ask the libreboot folks whehter they have any experience with external PCIe devices.

yes, with what I have found so far, it should work in terms of setup. I thought maybe it's not related to the libreboot/GNUboot aspect, but more something of a possible misconfiguration.

ah, so we don't know it worked with stock firmware before you flashed libreboot?

yes, it did work.
